# ページが変わっても"content_scripts"が反応しない

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension, youtube

YouTube 向けの拡張機能の作成をしており、manifestには以下のように記述しました。

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":[
            "https://www.youtube.com/*"
        ],
        "js":[
            "content_script.js"
        ]
    }
],
```

`youtube.com` のページを開くと反応するのですが、その後動画をクリックして `www.youtube.com/watch?v=_somePath` に変わっても反応はしませんでした。
どのようにすれば変化を感知することができるでしょうか？

**試してみたこと：**
最初から `www.youtube.com/watch?v=_somePath` に飛んでみると反応しました。
このことから YouTube で動画をクリックすると、動画をどこからか取ってきて描画しているだけなのでしょうか？

可能性としてはscriptとからPathの変化を自動で検知するプログラムを埋めて、"content_scripts"は最初の一回だけ発火させる方法が考えられるのですが、自分の力量不足でできませんでした。

調べてもわからなかったので質問させていただきます。
教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

多分解決いたしましたので質問を閉じさせていただきます。

"background_scripts"を使用しchrome apiからchrome.tabs.onUpdatedを拾ってきてcontextに送るのが最短なようです。少し手間がかかりますがやってみたいと思います。